# Is it possible to get default Facebook Group profile pictures?

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api

According to the [officlal Facebook document](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/), it seems that Facebook Graph API can treat Facebook Group profile pictures.  However, the [picture link](https://graph.facebook.com/195466193802264/picture) provided at *Connections* section on the document doesn't return the proper image.  The URL redirects to */images/icons/group-types/large/default.png*, which is apparently a path for default profile picture, but it actually returns JSON that has data like this:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /icons/group-types/large/default.png",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

Is this a bug of Facebook?  Are there any ideas to avoid this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug, to workaround it, get the image as a String instead of a HTTP redirect:

https://graph.facebook.com/195466193802264?fields=picture

The Response is:

```
"picture": "/images/icons/group-types/large/default.png"
```

parse that, and if you get back a relative URL, prepend it with `http://www.facebok.com`

In this specific case, it works: [Link here](http://www.facebook.com/images/icons/group-types/large/default.png)

In the meantime, you should [File a bug report](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/) and get this updated in the API

Comment: I confirmed that Facebook fixed the bug recently: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/175832325866475